# How to run Hadoop cluster in Docker containers on Apple M1 (Apple Silicon)

Tags: docker, hadoop, apple-m1

I just got my new Mac Mini and am trying to run Hadoop cluster in Docker containers on it.
I checked out this [repo](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop) on GitHub. However, it has only x64_64 Docker images.

Any tips will welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install with this repo https://github.com/YanYunNN/hadoop-cluster-docker-m1.
It worked on my Macbook (chip Apple M1 Pro). Hope this works for you too :)